# Why does Telnet client send data after each key stroke

Tags: windows, telnet

I made a Node js tcp server to listen on port 5000 using `net`

```
_createServer(){
    var self = this;
    net.createServer(function(socket){
        self._attachDefaultHandlers(socket);
    }).listen(this.settings.port);
    return this;
}
```

Whenever I create a telnet client

`telnet localhost 5000`

I connect to the server. The problem is every time i type, data is sent. Why does telnet not wait for me to press enter?

Comment: Thanks. Why though does `console.log(data)` in `Node` server return `<Buffer 45>` ? I've seen examples where typing "Hello" would log "Hello" in this case..?

Comment: *"Why does telnet not wait for me to press enter?"* - Because it's implemented not to wait for you to press [Enter]. With the obvious out of the way, why don't you ask the real question?

Comment: @terrywinkleheimer Because Node doesn't assume any encoding for client's input. If you wish, you can globally set encoding by `socket.setEncoding('utf8')`

Answer (score 1):

This is how windows shell responses to Telnet protocol by design. In order to achieve what you want, you can try Putty, a third party terminal simulator, it does a far better job than CMD in communicating through SSH/Telnet.